# Vim: how do I swap two characters?

Tags: vim

Is there a fast command to change

```
Cnotrol
```

to

```
Control
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

While in normal mode, with your cursor on top of the first character to swap, you can type <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to delete one character and **p**ut it after the cursor, effectively swapping the two characters.

One possibly useful command (taken straight from [the Vim page on swapping](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines)) would be

```
:nnoremap <silent> gc xph
```

to map <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (or another command of your choice) to swapping two characters. Note that the `h` simply moves the cursor back to its original position, on top of the first of the two characters to be swapped.

Comment: x: equivalent to "cut to clipboard"
p: equivalent to "paste from clipboard"

Comment: @WadihM. to be precise the result of `x` is stored in a `""` register (which is responsible for the last yank/cut operation). It can be observed by checking out all registers at `:reg`

Comment: xp is a way, but not the best. A question. Can you repeat the action with the dot command? I remember reading about a way 20 years back, but as a beginner I didn't memorize it as it didn't seem important. I am sure we could use the dot and repeat it, if we used THAT way. Still looking.

Answer (score 94):

<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

This swaps the current character with the next.

Answer (score 24):

You can also just use `Xp` with the cursor being on the second character. That way you stay on the same position without defining a new mapping.

Answer (score 5):

If you have some common missspellings you can also use the abbreviation feature to correct these as you type. For example, I often mistype 'String' as 'Stirng', the following command fixes these while typing:

```
inoreab <buffer> Stirng String
```

Comment: or, if you need something that fixes 4 thousands of these https://github.com/chip/vim-fat-finger :)

Comment: Ohh, this is way better than just setting it so vim highlights these typos for me! +1