# Swap two characters atomically, so that it can be repeated with "."

Tags: vim

The idiom for swapping two characters in Vim is `xp`.

See the help at [`:h 04.5`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_04.html#04.5), final paragraph, and [Vim: how do I swap two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1529414).

But very occasionally I need to do two or more swap operations in a row. I'm often surprised that what feels like a single operation to me, `xp`, is actually two operations to Vim. This makes it impossible to repeat `xp` with `.`. (Or atomic undo with `u`.)

Is there a way to swap two characters in a single operation that I can quickly repeat with `.`?

Comment: I can understand the desire for being able to repeat with `.`. I often have similar pet peeves that I want, but `xp` is not much slower than `.` and by the time you figure out a solution that works it will be a big ugly function in your vimrc that you just want to delete and you'll have learned something but wasted net working time - at least that's my personal experience in these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimcasts.org has published [an episode](http://vimcasts.org/e/61) that addresses this very problem.

As @Jeremy guessed the solution is to use the [***repeat.vim***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136) plugin. Then simply add the following [`<Plug>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3CPlug%3E) mapping and key mapping to your vimrc.

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Transpose xp:call repeat#set("\<Plug>Transpose")<CR>
nmap cp <Plug>Transpose
```

The mapping shown here uses `cp`. `cp` is the new `xp`, repeatable with `.` but otherwise exactly the same.

Now all that remains is getting used to it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't ideal, but if you store xp as a macro, it will be repeatable after you've executed the macro.  So instead of xp, you're using, say @s (for swap).  Then @@ will repeat it.  Not as nice as ., but it does work.

Edit:  You know, I'm sure there's a way to accomplish this with some vimscript and tpope's [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat).  Sadly, my vimscript is not up to snuff.  I got this far - maybe someone can correct where I'm going wrong?

```
fun! DoSwap()
  :normal xp
  silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Swap",1)
endfun
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Swap :call DoSwap()<CR>
nmap <Leader>s <Plug>Swap
```

The problem with this is that once you enter `\s`, it does indeed swap the characters you're on, and it DOES repeat when you hit `.`, but it jumps to the beginning of the line first, which is not what you want.  But I do think this can be done, I'm just not all the way there.

Comment: . will only repeat the last operation (p), not the entire macro (@s)

Comment: BTW, I think that registering a macro is indeed the best thing that can be done here.  Just remove "and then . will repeat it" from your answer, and I will be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @Bolo you're absolutely correct.  I don't know where I got the idea that . repeated a macro.  It doesn't even make sense if the way a macro works is by repeating your keystrokes.  Corrected to suggest using @@ to repeat instead.

Comment: Similarly, you could just do `:norm xp` the first time and then `@:` and `@@` to repeat. Same idea - less "fun!".

Comment: It seems to me that `@@` is no shorter than `xp`, but takes the time to set up the macro, so the end result is it's using a macro just to use one, without any savings or saved time.

Comment: I tend to agree, @theTinMan.  Aside from using some kind of vimscript function, I don't think there's a way to do it, and there's not really a point in using a function just to save a keystroke.  I'd be interested to know how to make it repeatable using repeat.vim, though, even though I don't think you're really gaining anything by using . instead of xp.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. Suppose the cursor is on the "y" of the word "oyxgen".

In normal mode, type

```
2sxy<Esc>
```

Now the word reads "oxygen". Find the next instance of the typo (`fy`) and repeat the change (`.`).

Too bad this works only for the specific swap "yx" to "xy", so this isn't the definitive solution.